# Practical applications of polyhedra and polytopes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What are the practical applications of Polyhedra and Polytopes? Please mention the real life applications of polyhedra and polytopes. I haven't yet found any real life applications of these objects? Is construction work related to polyhedra and polytopes?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The set of solutions of a system of linear inequalities will generally be a polytope. And linear inequalities arise in applications all over the place, giving rise to the branch of Mathematics called Linear Programming.